# Changing terminationGracePeriodSeconds value doesn't getting effected during new release

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sleep, graceful-shutdown

I have to changed the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` from 30 to 120 in Kubernetes deployment manifest file but when I am deploying using helm:

```
helm upgrade --install <chartname> --values <valuesfilename>
```

The old pods getting terminated immediately and new pods started running.

But the expected behavior is to keep the old pods in terminating state and continue its current processes for 120 seconds as defined.

What else could be missing here?

Does this solve my issue here?

```
containers:
  - name: containername
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: [ "/bin/sleep", "20" ]
```

One question I had is does adding sleep command stops execution of current processes of the pod and just sleeps while it is in terminating state?

Answer (score 2):

The Kubernetes parameter `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` decides on how much time Kubernetes waits until it forcefully kills your container. In other words, when Kubernetes wants to terminate your Pod, it does the following:

1. Kubernetes sends `SIGTERM` to your container
2. Kubernetes waits max. `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` for the following sequence of operations to happen:

   - Container stops normally
   - `PreStop` hook executes
3. Kubernetes sends `SIGKILL` to your container (and your `PreStop` container) and therefore terminates them forcefully

Note that your container and the `PreStop` containers are not executed at the same time, but synchronously, one by one.

Read more at [Kubernetes Hook Handler Execution](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-handler-execution).

Comment: Does adding sleep command stops execution of current processes of the pod and just sleeps while it is in terminating state???

does my prestop execution effects my actual container process which it currently handles?

Comment: No, `preStop` container does not stop the main container. The main container receives the SIGTERM signal and stops gracefully. Only after it's stopped, `preStop` container starts.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it is expected behavior for `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`, as it is *optional* duration in seconds the pod needs to terminate gracefully.

On pod termination - the lifecycle is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) -  pod receives `terminating` state and it is removed from the endpoints list of all services and stops getting new traffic. `SIGTERM` signal is immediately sent to the processes running in pod, and Kubernetes is waiting for the pod to stop normally on its own
during the grace period specified in `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` option. As soon as `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` expires, the Pod is forcefully killed by `SIGKILL` signal. In your case, the processes in the pod were just shutdown normally before 120 seconds of grace period have passed.

In its turn, `preStop`  hook is called immediately before a pod is terminated, which means that the hook will be executed prior to `kubectl` sends `SIGTERM` to the pod. As stated in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks), the hook **must** complete before the `TERM` signal to stop the container is sent. `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` is happening in parallel with the preStop hook and the `SIGTERM` signal and its countdown begins before the `preStop` hook is executed. The pod will eventually terminate within the pod's termination grace period, regardless of the hook completion.

Therefore, on receiving `sleep` command for `preStop`  hook, pod already marked as `Terminating` but the processes inside of it are not yet terminated - so the container can complete all the active requests during this period.

Comment: Thanks this is a really good reply and helped me big time!